# Clean input before change

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I'm using handsontable 0.35.1 with a float column. Aim is to allow users to copy paste from spreadsheets (and csvs opened in excel). Problem is, that it comes with some junk that i need to get rid of. Some examples of inputs which are not correctly validated are:

```
1,000.00
USD 100.00
'10000.00  '  //note there are trailing spaces
```

I would like to find a way i can manipulate input right before it's written. The only way i've found so far is with beforeChange, but the problem is validation. The system changes input, but seems to have validated already. If i blur in and blur out again, it works.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hassan_rehman/xpvt214o/347421/). Steps to reproduce: Enter number a123 -- which should be corrected to 123 and validated as a correct number.

I've tried using beforeValidation instead, but it doesn't work as i intend.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `beforePaste` callback to clean your input

```
  options = {
    columns: [
      { type: 'date' },
      { type: 'numeric', numericFormat: {pattern: '0,0.00'} }
  ],
  colHeaders: ["Date", "Float"],
  beforePaste: (data, coords) => {
    data.forEach((col, colIndex) => {
        col.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
        let value = row.trim().replace(/[^0-9\.\-\+]/g, '')
        data[colIndex][rowIndex] = value
      })
    })
    return true
  },
}
$('#hot-sheet').handsontable(options)
```

here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/348195/

Note: you can't create new data array, you've to update data array instead of creating new.

Comment: beforePaste will only resolve the issue of copy pasting. Which is practically enough yes, but not complete. I want to be able to 'clean' any input provided by the user

Answer (score 1):

I updated the example https://jsfiddle.net/fma4uge8/29/ this works all in 1 function.

```
function trimFloat(value) {
    return value.trim().replace(/[^0-9\.\-\+]/g, '');
}

options = {
  columns: [
    { type: 'date' },
    { type: 'numeric', numericFormat: {pattern: '0,0.00'}, trimWhitespace: true }
  ],
  colHeaders: ["Date", "Float"],
  beforeChange: function(changes, source){
    let that = this;
    _.each(changes, function(change){
      if (_.isString(change[3])) {
            let value = trimFloat(change[3]);
          //prevent endless loop
          if (value !== change[3]) {
            change[3] = trimFloat(change[3]);
                        that.setDataAtCell(change[0], change[1], change[3]);       
          }
      }
    })
  }
}
$('#hot-sheet').handsontable(options)
```

Comment: This works, but is still not ideal. The entire logic of 'cleaning' the input runs twice. Once to change the input and once to validate. What i'd like is for HoT to consider validate the values as output by beforeChange method. So that default validations are run after inputs are changed.

Comment: @saGii see my update, this version is all in the `beforeChange`